# Which library do I have to link for the GNU libc extension tdestroy

Tags: gnu, glibc, libc

I am trying to link a c program that I compiled with the gcc compiler. The linker does not find the symbol `tdestroy` which is a gnu extension to libc (`#define __USE_GNU` followed by `#include <search.h>`). Is there an additional library that I have to link with in order for the linker to find this symbol?

~Update~: I just realized that it does indeed link on my Linux environment but on Windows, I still get a `undefined reference to 'tdestroy'` error with mingw/gcc, even after using `_GNU_SOURCE` instead of `__USE_GNU`.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `__USE_GNU`. That's an internal GLIBc macro. The [tdestroy man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/tdestroy) says the macro you need
to define at the beginning is `_GNU_SOURCE`.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <search.h>
void *td = tdestroy;
int main(){}
```

compiles with no linker error (no extra libraries needed).

Answer (score 2):

You should never define `__USE_GNU` (sic), it is an internal symbol.  You need to define `_GNU_SOURCE`, see [Feature Test Macros](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Feature-Test-Macros.html).

If you do that, the `tdestroy` function will become available.

It is also a good idea to build with `-Werror=implicit-function-declaration`, so that missing prototypes lead to a compiler failure, and not later to a linker failure.